# solr search with keywords having space not giving proper results

Tags: solr, lucene

I have list of keywords few of them are below

Cheap hotels
Dubai hotel
extended hotel
....
..

I have store(storeName:HotelsStore) for this and added the keywords above(which have white space) to my store and doing solr indexing. If we search with 
 "Cheap hotels" my store:HotelsStore is not showing reults.

But If I add "Cheaphotels" without space and indexing. If I search with "Cheaphotels" then my desired store(HotelsStore) is showing  in results.

Note: We are using lucene 5.4 and solr 5.4.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Syamala.

Comment: What is the field type and what analyzers are applied to the field? This is most certainly an issue with how the tokens are created for the field, either through the filters or the tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate word parts using WordDelimiterFilter filter on **storeName** field.

You could customise this filter how you want.

Just example:

> One way of doing so is to specify generateWordParts="1"
>   catenateWords="1" in the analyzer used for indexing, and
>   generateWordParts="1" in the analyzer used for querying. Given that
>   the current StandardTokenizer immediately removes many intra-word
>   delimiters, it is recommended that this filter be used after a
>   tokenizer that leaves them in place (such as WhitespaceTokenizer).

```
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"
            />
```

**GENERATE_WORD_PARTS** set to 1

```
Causes parts of words to be generated:

"HotelsStore" => "Hotel" "Store"
```

https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html

Comment: Thanks for your response @Oyeme. .Cheap hotels, Dubai hotel, extended hotel are the keywords adding to store(it's name is:hotelsStore) as keywords not in storeName. We are already using "WordDelimiterFilterFactory"  and I have used like below catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"  but still facing same problem.  Thanks..Syamala.

Comment: Could you please provide more information of field, filters that you are using? You could also use analyzer to see why field is not showing.